# Can RabbitMQ clustering actually be used to support high availability?

Tags: cluster-computing, rabbitmq, message-queue, high-availability

I've been looking at RabbitMQ as a candidate for a highly available and reliable message broker. What I need is a message broker running on n physical machines that will keep running even after hardware or network failure of a single instance. Individual messages will need to be transmitted reliably with at-least-once semantics. The cluster will also need to be able to heal itself and allow a crashed instance to be restarted without additional manual invention!

Reading the RabbitMQ documentation, there are some scary caveats in the clustering section such as "Brokers must be connected via reliable LAN links". Other sections have also mentioned that restarting a crashed node may require some manual intervention. Can RabbitMQ meet my requirements and if not, are there other OSS alternatives that do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box silver bullet with RabbitMQ for the requirements you describe. If you want to address your real business requirements with RabbitMQ, you will need to build in some extra capabilities that are probably specific to your application. In this case, you may need to seek guidance from either the RabbitMQ discussion list or google for RabbitMQ consulting.

Note that you don't *repair* crashed nodes in a cluster, you *replace* them. You could wrap the Rabbit start script with something that checks Rabbit's exit code and, in the event of a crash, delete the node and create a brand new one.